# Insert Query not working insert form syntax error

Tags: jquery, sql, netbeans

I been trying to figure out whats wrong with my query I am beginner hoping for suggestion below is my query thank you

```
stmt.executeUpdate ("INSERT INTO reseve1( Customer Name, Contact Number, Email 
Address, Venue, Date, Time, Price, Balance) "+ "VALUES ("+"\""+cx1+"\""+","+"\""+contactnum11+"\""+","+"\""+"\""+email1+"\""+","+"\""+"\""+ venuee+"\""+","+"\""+"\""+Date1+"\""+","+"\""+"\""+Time1+"\""+","+"\""++"\""+","+"\""+"\""+Price1+"\""+","+"\""+Balance+"\""+")");
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters instead of munging query strings with input values.

Comment: 1) Learn to read (I'm not being nasty): The error ***message*** gives you guidance about what & where the problem is. Since you have not bothered to tell us what that message is, we cannot even tell whether the error is in the code you've shown, or in the SQL statement that code builds up. 2) Use parameters as Gordon suggests. It makes your code much easier to read; so less likely to make mistakes.

Comment: I'll clarify my previous comment. I'm not saying learn 'how' to read. I'm saying _learn **to be in the habit** of reading your error messages very carefully_. Make sure you understand them properly. They usually give you a good indication of what's wrong; especially if you take the time to understand the terminology. Even when they don't, they do provide clues about what to look for; and at a minimum, they provide something to search online for.

Answer (score -1):

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
string query1 = "insert into reseve1(Customer_Name, Contact_Number, Email, Address, Venue, Date, Time, Price, Balance) values ("+ Customer_Name.Text + "," + Contact_Number.Text + "," + Email_Address.Text + "," + Venue.Text + ","+ Date.Text +  "," + Time.Text +  ","+ Price.Text +  "," + Balance.Text + "," ")";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);

Comment: You're also guessing. Why do you bother trying to answer a nonsense question? And by using different identifiers OP cannot copy-paste your code to plug it in. So the fact that you didn't bother to provide any explanation makes your guess pretty much useless. _Note that OP hasn't bothered to provide the error message **at all**._ So for all you know the problem could be due to an invalid identifier. Wild unfounded guesses are not helpful; you gain nothing by wasting your time trying to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO reseve1(Customer_Name, Contact_Number, Email_Address, Venue, Date, Time, Price, Balance) " + 
"VALUES (:cname,:cnumber,:mail,:location,:dateValue,:timeValue,:priceVal,:balanceAmount)";

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);


query.setString("cname", cx1.getText());
query.setInteger("cnumber", contactnum11.getInt());
query.setString("mail", email1.getText());
query.setString("location", venuee.getText());
query.setString("dateValue", Date1);
query.setString("timeValue", Time1.getText());
query.setString("priceVal", venuee.getInt());
query.setInteger("balanceAmount", Balance.getInt());
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What makes you think this has the slightest possibility of working? Do you even understand why OP was trying to build up the Sql statement in the first place (as opposed to the hard-coded query you propose)? _Wild guesses of possible answers with zero understanding are usually less than helpful._

Comment: thank you I already solved it by checking my syntax. Thank you